# ip_conntrack ideal or not for server stability

Tags: linux, networking, security, kernel, ddos

By default the module ip_conntrack is installed into the kernel. My question is simple, is having ip_conntrack a performance booster for better tracking of connections? On VPS nodes they do not have it installed and a lot of people point out that you need to tune for GET Floods and other attacks so does NOT having ip_conntrack make your server more stable from such attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ip_conntrack` is required for stateful packet filtering in `netfilter` (the Linux kernel packet filter).